# Angular finding siblings, editing style and playing video on mouseenter mouseleave

Tags: angular, typescript

how can I find the sibling with a `video` tag, change the style and play the video in angular 4? It was easy using jquery, but there is no jquery/dont want to use jquery in my project. All I found was `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` template and I don't know how to convert the `siblings('video')` and `.css()` to angular.

```
//jquery
//.html
<div class="portrait">
    <div class="selector"></div>
    <img src="~/images/example.png" />
    <video loop="loop" class="video">
        <source src="~/videos/example.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".selector").hover(
            function () {
                let selector = $(this);
                let vid = selector.siblings("video").css("display", "inline");
                vid.get(0).play();
            },
            function () {
                let selector = $(this);
                let vid = selector.siblings("video").css("display", "none");
                vid.get(0).pause();
            }
        );

        $(".selector").on('click', function () {
            var src = $(this).siblings('video');
            console.log(src.children('source').attr('src'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is the angular code..

```
//angular
//.html
<div *ngFor="let name of names" class="portrait">
    <div class="selector" (mouseenter)="show()" (mouseleave)="hide()"></div>
    <img src="../assets/{{name}}.png" />
    <video loop="loop" class="video">
        <source src="../assets/{{name}}.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>

//.ts
show(): void {
    // get sibling with a video tag
    // change style display to inline
    // play the video
}

hide(): void {
    // get sibling with a video tag
    // change style display to none
    // pause the video
}
```

Comment: Angular has a radically different way of working than jQuery. You don't doDOM manipulation with Angular. You use a template, that automatically generates the DOM based on the state of its component. You need to start thinking in those terms, rather than DOM manipulation terms, otherwise, you'll hit walls all the time. What do you actually want to achieve? Have you taken the time to learn how Angular works?

Comment: @JBNizet I just finish the tutorial and read some docs in angular.io, so in angular way, what is the best approach to the the siblings with video? what i'm trying to do is in when i hover to a div, it will show the video and play it, when i mouse leave in the div, it will hide and pause the video.

Comment: To hide or show an element, you can use the [style.display]="...". Based on a boolean value in the model, the display should be "block" or "none". To access the video element and be able to call its pause() and play() methods, you can use a template variable #theVideo. Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Il7YY0ah2PTid9HriaZA?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, works great, I knew that you can past the `video` as a parameter. and i change the styling to `video.style.display`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Angular too, I will do it like this:

in the .ts code, change the variable "names" to an array of object called "videos", it will be like this

```
this.videos = [
{
    name: "video1",
    hidden: true
},
{
    name: "video2",
    hidden: true
}]

show(video): void {
  video.hidden = false;  
}

hide(video): void {
  video.hidden = true;  
}
```

then in the template html,

```
<div *ngFor="let video of videos" class="portrait">
    <div class="selector" (mouseenter)="show(video)" (mouseleave)="hide(video)"></div>
    <img src="../assets/{{video.name}}.png" />
    <video loop="loop" class="video" [class.hidden]="video.hidden">
        <source src="../assets/{{video.name}}.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

in css

```
.video {
    display: block;
}
.video.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

the code in the methods show hide is simple, you can do it in the template.
to show hide you can also use *ngIf="!video.hidden"